# I need to check every owner of an object involved in a trigger permissions

Tags: apex, trigger, permissions, sharing

I have an object called Albaran__c, (it's set on private sharing mode). I have a trigger that shares every record involved on the trigger with the owner of the Account we do reference on the field Cliente__c.

The problem is that we do Jitterbit updates of all Albaran__c , so the amount of Albaran__c that cause trigger are quite high. The problem is i'm getting Too many SOQL queries on my code.

The problem is the User Record Access queries requires UserID [Single ID] so i cant avoid do that query out of an For loop.

THis is the code of my trigger:

```
trigger Trigger_Visibilitat_CuentasAlbaran on Albaran__c (after insert, after update) {

    List <AccountShare> AccountShrs = new List <AccountShare>(); 
    AccountShare AccountShr;
    Map <id,Albaran__c> MapAlbaranold = new Map<id,Albaran__c>();
    Albaran__c old;
    if(Trigger.isUPdate) {
        for(Albaran__c a: Trigger.old) MapAlbaranold.put(a.id, a);    
    }
    Set<id> idsCuentasEmpresas = new Set<id>();
    for(Albaran__c albaran: Trigger.new) idsCuentasEmpresas.add(albaran.Cliente__c);
    Map <id,Account> MapCuentas = new Map <id,Account>();
    for(Account a: [SELECT id, OwnerID FROM Account WHERE id in: idsCuentasEmpresas]) {
        mapCuentas.put(a.Id, a);
    }
    for(Albaran__c albaran: Trigger.new){
        if(Trigger.isUpdate) old = MapAlbaranold.get(albaran.id);
        // compruebo que el usuario actual no tenga visibilidad actualmente
        boolean b = false;
        for(UserRecordAccess Ura: [SELECT RecordId, HasReadAccess, HasTransferAccess, MaxAccessLevel
        FROM UserRecordAccess
        WHERE UserId =: albaran.OwnerId
        AND RecordId =: albaran.Cliente__c]) {
            if(Ura.HasReadAccess) b=true;                               
        }
        if(!b) {
            // Instantiate the sharing objects
            AccountShr = new AccountShare();
            // Set the ID of record being shared
            AccountShr.AccountId = albaran.Cliente__c;
            // Set the ID of user or group being granted access
            AccountShr.UserOrGroupId = albaran.OwnerId;          
            // Set the access level
            AccountShr.AccountAccessLevel = 'Edit';
            AccountShr.CaseAccessLevel = 'Edit';
            AccountShr.OpportunityAccessLevel = 'Edit';
            AccountShr.RowCause = Schema.AccountShare.RowCause.Manual;        
            // Add objects to list for insert
            AccountShrs.add(AccountShr);
            // Insert sharing records and capture save result 
            // The false parameter allows for partial processing if multiple records are passed 
            // into the operation 
        } 
        // erase old ones
            if(Trigger.isUpdate && albaran.OwnerId != old.ownerId){
                List<AccountShare> sharesToDelete = [SELECT Id,UserOrGroupID 
                                                FROM AccountShare 
                                                WHERE UserOrGroupId =: old.OwnerId];
                if(!sharesToDelete.isEmpty()) Database.Delete(sharesToDelete, false);
            }


        }

        Database.SaveResult[] lsr = Database.insert(AccountShrs,false);

         integer i = 0;
        // Process the save results
        for(Database.SaveResult sr : lsr){
            Albaran__c albaran = Trigger.new.get(i);
            if(!sr.isSuccess()){
                // Get the first save result error
                Database.Error err = sr.getErrors()[0];              
                // Check if the error is related to a trivial access level
                // Access levels equal or more permissive than the object's default 
                // access level are not allowed. 
                // These sharing records are not required and thus an insert exception is 
                // acceptable. 
                if(!(err.getStatusCode() == StatusCode.FIELD_FILTER_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION  
                                               &&  err.getMessage().contains('AccessLevel'))){
                    // Throw an error when the error is not related to trivial access level.
                    trigger.newMap.get(albaran.id). addError('Unable to grant sharing access due to following exception: '
                       + err.getMessage());
                }
            }
            i++;
        }
}
```

Could you suggest some way to do that that could work for massive updates?

Thank you really much.

Comment: Are you asking how to refractor the code? Or the reason behind the error? You are getting the error of too many SOQL queries due to the fact that you have SOQL queries in the for loops, twice.

Comment: WEll i'm asking ow to refractor the code since i can't see a clear way to bulkify the code without losing needed information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the limits imposed by the UserRecordAccess object, your only two solutions are to either (a) reduce the batch size of Jitterbit so that it only loads a small set of records per API call (perhaps 50?), or (b) process your sharing asynchronously. I'd recommend using the Queueable interface, breaking your transactions into small chucks of perhaps 50 records, and processing them asynchronously. You'll still be giving access to the records near-real-time in most cases, with nothing more than a few seconds worth of delay per every couple hundred records.

Comment: I just read this but the problem was already solved yYesterday by doing what you suggested. 
I made the chucks of 15 records (i was still getting errors with 100-40 records) and other error i'm not quite sure why appears on jitterbit with 25-20, but finally made it work with 15. :)

Thank you anyway! :)

Answer (score 0):

You **can** move your query from your for-loop. First, create a Set of UserIDs and Cliente__c's. Then, you can change your query to:

```
[SELECT RecordId, HasReadAccess, HasTransferAccess, MaxAccessLevel
        FROM UserRecordAccess
        WHERE UserId IN : ownerIDs
        AND RecordId IN : clienteIDs]
```

You will have to create a map of Users (Map) and a map of Cliente's ( (Map) as well. This way, you can find the right information from the User/Cliente__c when needed. You can do something similar for the second query in your for-loop.

Have a look at this page for an example:
https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_triggers_bulk_idioms.htm

If you can't get it to work, let me know!

Comment: Actually i know how to bulkify the code the problem is that you can't do UserID IN: ownersIDs. 
It can only be the form UserId = [single ID]

But i actually find something to work with. 

If it solves the problem i post it since i didn't find nobody else asking for this concrete question. 

Thanks anyway Koen :). 

I post in few minutes.

Comment: Well, after some trying i realized the solution isn't as close as i initially thought. 

I can't see a clear way to bulkify the code in a way that works.

Comment: Actually the error you get is this if you use the codeyou suggested: 

Can filter on only UserId = [single ID], either RecordId = [single ID] or RecordId IN [list of IDs], and Has*Access = true